# MQTT + Telegraf + InfluxDB Error in plugin: invalid character

Tags: json, mqtt, influxdb, telegraf

for a sensor monitoring prototype, I am currently trying to set up a MQTT(mosquitto) + Telegraf + InfluxDB stack on Ubuntu 20.04. I configured telegraf.conf in the inputs.mqtt_consumer section with:

```
topics = [
    "sensors",
    "test"
]
...
data_format = "json"
json_string_fields = []
```

But when I try to send a mqtt message from shell on the local machine using e.g.

```
mosquitto_pub -h localhost -m {"a": 5} -t "test"
```

I just get an error message from telegraf:

```
E! [inputs.mqtt_consumer] Error in plugin: invalid character 'a' looking for beginning of object key string
```

Can anyone spot the problem and help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `-m` is a string, so it has to start and end with a single or double quote. So: `mosquitto_pub -h localhost -m "{\"a\":5}" -t "test"`

Comment: Hey JD Allen, thank you so much! You saved me a lot of time :-)

Comment: Ok...I'll mkae that an Answer then ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your command line.  The `-m` option is a string, so your command should look like this:

`mosquitto_pub -h localhost -m '{"a": 5}' -t "test"`